# Google Apps Script bound to spreadsheet not copied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Apps Script bound to a spreadsheet.
When I tried to copy the spreadsheet programmatically with the Google Sheets API, all the data was copied except for the Google Apps Script.
When trying to do the same operation manually, the script is copied, as expected.

Any idea why the script is not copied when using the API?

Comment: It'd help if you show the code that you have so far.